# Having problem with "moveTo" Block in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using "moveto" to reach at destination caller *Dryer*. *Dryer* have "queue" and "delay".
Now when agent come it first go to *Dryer* and then go to "queue" and then wait for its turn to go to *Dryer* for "delay".

What should happen is agent move to the "queue", wait for its turn to go to *Dryer*. How I can achieve that?

**My approach**

**1. MoveTo**

[image]

**2. Queue**

[image]

**3. Delay**

[image]

Comment: Not sure I see the problem. With the flowchart, agents will queue before entering the Dryer delay.

Comment: I think that I understand the problem. If the Dryer is busy, so the MoveTo Block transfers the agent to the dryer and returns back to the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you should do is use a conveyor block instead of a moveTo + queue blocks like this:
The conveyor will act as a queue and everything will be ok
[image: convey]

You will have to define the path for the conveyor and set the delay with capacity 1 and the location of the delay on the dryer

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put a `Node` with a radius 0 very close to the `Node` associated with the dryer and send the agents there.
See below each block where I associate it:

[image]

Good luck!